# hasClass doesn't fire up

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery

I have a bootstrap `navbar`,whenever and I have a button ,when I click the button the navbar items get displayed/hidden.
I have a `toggleClass("foo")` in the click of the button and the class also gets added,but when I try to do `hasClass("foo")` it does not work.

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function () {
    $('.selectedMenu').remove();
    $(this).toggleClass('active closed');
    if ($(this).hasClass(".active")) {
        alert("as");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the class selector (**.**) when using `hasClass`

Change

```
$(this).hasClass(".active")
```

to

```
$(this).hasClass("active")
```

**[hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)**

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't need to add the `.` in front of the class name as demonstrated [here](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

So try this:

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function () {
    $('.selectedMenu').remove();
    $(this).toggleClass('active closed');
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        alert("as");
    }
});
```